# How to prevent user from deleting a feature?

Tags: arcmap, events

How can I prevent the user from deleting a feature?

```
void m_editEvents_OnDeleteFeature(IObject obj)
        {
            // Code
        }
```

Comment: see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12332/31

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I faced the same task and have searched documentation and forums concerning this question.

At last I've ended on this Esri forum topic: [How to suppress AbortOperation message](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=64165%29).

I have used approach proposed in the last message of that topic although it is not very beautiful. This was in 9.3.1, may be there is better solution in 10.0 now.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your help i tried AbortOperation its work fine,
but its give me a message box,
how can i get rid of it, or change it ?

Comment: Read the last post in that topic, they are solving this problem there. PS it is better to post such additional questions in the comments to an answer.